# Is there a better way to print a string with cout up to N characters?

Tags: c++, vector

-edit- I am sending binary and not a string. My test is using html pages so in this example i am only using a string but my question is about binary, vectors and debugging with ostream. I make this clears some confusion.

I have the following code:

```
cout << string(&v[0]).substr(0, len);
```

Is there a better way to print the string *v* with cout up the length *len*?  I thought of doing v[len] = 0 but I an assertion is thrown with a size of 1. My code is:

```
vector<char> v;
v.reserve(1024*16); //required
v.resize(1); //so we can do &v[0]
recv(sockfd, &v[0], v.capacity(), 0);
while (l > 0)
{
    cout << string(&v[0]).substr(0, l);
    recv(sockfd, &v[0], v.capacity(), 0);
}
cout << "the size is " << v.size();
```

Comment: This code is broken. Horribly so. Using a vector to allocate an array (which is what is essentially happening there) is not only dangerous (vectors are MEANT to reallocate their internal arrays!) but also pointless.

Comment: At least use v.resize(1024*16) if you *must* use a vector, but as mentioned by dionadar, doing it this way is not a good idea and basically doesn't protect you from anything anyway and might lead to some interesting nights debugging this code.

Comment: what is wrong with his use of vector? if the size is dynamic, i don't see anything bad with it

Comment: (although in this case, it's not dynamic... but it may in his code, we don't know)

Comment: he uses a vector<char> which internally creates a char[] to hold whatever you put in there. BUT resizing an array is impossible, so if you decide to resize the vector (intentionally or not) it creates a NEW char.

He however now has a invalid char* to the begin of the first array. BAD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the method ostream::write on the cout object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<char> test;
  test.push_back('a');
  test.push_back('b');
  test.push_back('c');

  cout.write(&test[0], 3);
  cout << endl;
}
```

Outputs:

> abc

Since ostream::write returns an ostream& containing *this, you can even do

```
cout.write(&test[0], 3) << endl;
```

but I'm not sure that is actually any better (or clearer).

Answer (score 6):

```
vector<char> v;
v.reserve(1024*16); //required
v.resize(1); //so we can do &v[0]
recv(sockfd, &v[0], v.capacity(), 0);
```

That code has a bug. Calling `reserve` will only guarantee you that you can push_back at least that many elements until references and iterators to the vector are invalidated again (through a possible reallocation of the used buffer). It will *not* allow you to write into v[0..1024*16-1], as you do there with `recv`. You have to do

```
v.resize(1024*16); //required
```

to actually have that many elements available and actually pass `v.size()` instead of `v.capacity()`.

For your substring operation, i would probably do

```
std::string str(&v[0], n);
std::cout << str;
```

Where n ranges from 0 up to v.size(). You can use `std::min(n, v.size())` to guarantee that, if n could be larger in your case and you need an upper limit.

(on a side node, i would avoid having a variable called "l" (ell) there, because it can look very much like an "1" (one), which can confuse the hell out of people)

Comment: from what i read you can in fact write into 0-1024*16-1 elements and it is guaranteed to be continuous, however elements from size to capacity are not constructed/initialized.

Comment: it's not right, because the vector does not have so many elements. you can only write to/ read from up to v[0..v.size()-1] of course.

Comment: btw, if you need a constant sized buffer, it's better to use boost::array<char, 1024*16> v; then pass v.data() and v.size() . or an array on the stack - though raw arrays should be avoided... u know, danger around the corner

Comment: std::string str(v.begin(), v.begin()+n); would be less hackish.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the size to 1?
When you reserve the space the space is available for the vector to grow into (without reallocating). But who said it was safe to use directly? I have seen (debug) implementations that add a warning buffer just after size() modify these bits and it would generate an assert next time it checked. You should only be reading/writing from 0 -> size().

NB This will then also allow you to use v[len] = '\0';

```
vector<char> v(1024*16);

std::size_t  len = recv(sockfd, &v[0], v.size(), 0);
while (len > 0)
{
    v[len] = '\0';
    cout << &v[0];
    len = recv(sockfd, &v[0], v.size(), 0);
}
```

Note this is probably not the best way to read a string.
I would pass length information over the stream so you know when there is not more information to read then read only as much as is required.

Comment: If i use do v.clear(); v.push_back(data) a bunch of times. I would need to resize it capacity again? which would construct all my chars and in chars case no ctor but initial it to fillData? thats annoying, especially if i write/send many 128bytes and need a buf of at least 16k. Is there a way to...

Comment: is there a way to resize w/o initializing the data to fillValue? if not that debug impl would annoy me in this prj and it be debug imple vs avoiding potentially a lot of overhead with resize. also, ostream.write(ptr, len); solves my question.

Answer (score -2):

**See comments:**  I stand corrected.  I was mininformed.  However, I still think it's nuts to rely on internals like this.  The last microsoft compiler I used violated C99 standards causing me no end of grief.  If they can't get return values right on *vsnprinf()* or *new,* do you really want to rely on errata like this?

<strike>You are making assumptions regarding how vector is implemented.  You are assuming that v[1] comes right after v[0] in memory.</strike>

There is a difference between **char buf[]; & buf[1] ==  & buf[0] + 1**  and  **vector v; & v[1] ==  & v[0] + 1**.  The char array uses pointer arithmetic.  The vector uses operator[].   How the vector stores data internally, whether it is adjacent or not, is up to that vector class.

While your code may still work, this is still a **BAD** thing!  It makes your software brittle, causing it to break in strange and expected ways when you least expect it!

This is a ideal situation for a temporary char array on the local stack.  The size is small.  You have a hardcoded maximum size.

If the size wasn't constant, I'd still use a small local char-array buffer on the stack.  I'd just append it to a C++ std::string after each iteration.  (Yes, std::strings can store binary values including multiple null characters.)

**recv()** returns how many bytes it read.  Vector **v** doesn't automagically pick this up.  So you need to store and use that value.

I suggest:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE  (1024*16)
#define FLAGS        0

int  received = 0;
int  total    = 0;
char buffer [ BUFFER_SIZE + 1 ];

memset( buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE + 1 );

received = recv( sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, FLAGS );

if ( received > 0 )
{
  copy( buffer + total,
        buffer + total + received,
        ostream_iterator<char>(cout) );

  total += received;
}

while( (received > 0) && (total < BUFFER_SIZE) )
{
  received = recv( sockfd, buffer + total, BUFFER_SIZE - total, FLAGS );

  if ( received > 0 )
  {
    copy( buffer + total,
          buffer + total + received,
          ostream_iterator<char>(cout) );

    total += received;
  }
}

buffer [ total ] = '\0';
buffer [ BUFFER_SIZE ] = '\0';

cout << "The total size is " << total << endl;
```

Comment: well. actually vector being contiguous is one of its key features. you are guaranteed that &v[1] == &v[0] + 1 is true if the vector contains at least 2 elements.

Comment: it wasn't that way in c++98. but it was fixed in c++03. read http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/

Comment: I stand corrected.  Original posting updated.  But I still think it's nuts to rely on internals like this.  The last microsoft compiler I used violated C99 standards causing me no end of grief.  Do you really want to rely on errata like this?  Especially when there's no need?

Comment: When did Microsoft compilers ever claim to support C99?