# c++ vector<char> and sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, vector

Is there a way to call send / recv passing in a vector ?

What would be a good practice to buffer socket data in c++ ? For ex: read until \r\n or until an upper_bound ( 4096 bytes )

Comment: You mean you want to pass the entire data structure as is?

Comment: instead of:
char b[100];
send(z,b,100,0);
i would like to send a vector. i may have found the answer in a different thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550797/is-there-a-better-way-to-print-a-string-with-cout-up-to-n-characters
is that a good practice though?

Comment: Using the adress of the first element is fine. So you can use it for a send(). The standard guarantees that all elements are in contiguous memory. The reverse will not work though because you may not have the correct size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::vector<char> b(100); 
send(z,&b[0],b.size(),0);
```

*Edit*: I second [Ben Hymers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399891/c-vectorchar-and-sockets/1400077#1400077) and [me22's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399891/c-vectorchar-and-sockets/1400289#1400289) comments. Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339470/how-to-get-the-address-of-the-stdvector-buffer-start-most-elegantly/1339767#1339767) for a generic implementation that doesn't try to access the first element in an empty vectors.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on what sbi said, std::vector is guaranteed to have the same memory layout as a C-style array. So you can use &myVector[0], the address of the 0th element, as the address of the start of an array, and you can use myVector.size() elements of this array safely. Remember that those are both invalidated as soon as you next modify the vector though!

Comment: To clarify what Ben said, it's invalidated as soon as you modify the vector itself, not the contents of the vector. In other words, if you cause the vector to reallocate its contents, the address you got back from &v[0] is invalid.

Comment: I wouldn't say "same memory layout", since sizeof(vector<T>) is a constant, but rather state the actual guarantee of continuity: For all T != bool, vector<T> v, i in [0, v.size()), you know that &v[i] == &v[0] + i.

Answer (score 6):

One thing to watch out for: &v[0] is technically not allowed if the vector is empty, and some implementations will assert at you, so if you get buffers from others, be sure they're not empty before using this trick.

C++0x's vector has a .data() member function (like std::string's) to avoid this problem and make things clearer.